# Is it possible to start an Adobe Flex app on OS X with just the AIR runtime and the .swf

Tags: apache-flex, macos, air, adobe

I know it is possible to run an Adobe Flex compiled .swf from the command-line using the `adl` command-line tool.

Is there an equivalent way to run a Flex .swf from the command-line using the system installed AIR runtime?

My question applies to OS X, but I'd interested to know about other platforms also.

**UPDATE**: This question is now somewhat obsolete. As of AIR 3, there is now an 'officially supported' way to bundle the AIR runtime with an application, using the ['captive runtime' deployment option](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say No!  A SWF is not the same as an AIR application.  If you take that SWF's code and compile it into an AIR application; then you should be able to install and run it independent of the browser or any development tools.

I suppose in theory you could create an AIR application where you give it the location of a SWF and use [SWFLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html) to load the actual SWF.  I don't think that is quite what you're after.

There is a stand alone Flash Player which is different from AIR and different from the browser plugin.  You can get it [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html).  You can use that to run the SWF as if it were a local app.  I wouldn't count on your users having that, though.

You can also load a local SWF in the browser and let the flash player plugin handle it.

Comment: OK, but then it *should* be possible. If Adobe make it possible to launch Flex SWFs in debug mode from the command line using adl, they should make it possible to launch them with the standard AIR runtime without requiring myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp.

Comment: @JAmie Bullock IF you launch an AIR app in debug mode, don't you need the AIR runtime installed?  I thought it was installed as part of the SDK.  When launching a Flex SWF in debug mode doesn't it launch in a browser?

Comment: Aha! From Adobe's docs: "ADL uses a runtime included with the SDK". But no, it doesn't launch in a browser -- it's a standalone app. I also notice there is a -nodebug flag for adl. So, theoretically it looks like I could bundle adl + the AIR SDK's runtime with my app and avoid the requirement for users to install AIR at all...

Comment: @Jamie Bullock As I said in my original post, there is a stand alone Flash Player which is different from the AIR Runtime and different from a browser plugin.  That said, I was pretty sure you need an AIR runtime installed to development AIR apps.  I thought a runtime was installed as part of the AIR SDK.

Comment: @jamie Bullock  Per docs http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=installing__air_1.html "The Adobe AIR runtime allows you to run AIR applications on the desktop. You can install the runtime in the following ways: By setting up an AIR development environment such as the AIR SDK, Flex Builder 3, or the Flex 3 SDK (which includes the AIR command line development tools)" As such,  I Believe to run ADL you need the AIr runtime installed.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested to run an AIR app without the need to install the application.

Copy the following folders from your Flex SDK

- bin
- runtimes\air

as well as all files from your "release" (bin-debug) folder of your project.(Don't build a release build!).

now you can run the application with "adl app.xml".

Though there was AIR runtime installed on the PC I think it should be possible without it too. 
The original question was a bit different though, maybe it's helpful anyway.

Comment: Thanks. As of AIR 3, there's now an officially supported way to include the runtime with your app using 'captive runtime' deployment: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader. I've updated my question accordingly.